# Robot class - Screenshot a specific frame/component while Java App is minimized / in background

Tags: java, swing, awt

How can I capture a specific component in my Java application as opposed to my full primary monitor?

Current code example of how I collect the image:

```
    Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
    BufferedImage image = null;
    try {//take the screenshot and store in buf img
        image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(screenRect);
    } catch (AWTException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Example of components I want to screen shot would be JFrame, Applet, and JPanels. An example with any of those would be satisfactory in answering this question.

**EDIT:**
This code solves the issue of allowing you to run and take screenshots while minimized or in background. Thanks to Dando18.

```
public static BufferedImage createImage(JComponent comp) {
    int w = comp.getWidth();
    int h = comp.getHeight();
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
    comp.paint(g);
    return bi;
}
```

**Remaining issues:**

- When I take a screenshot by using getComponent or getContentPane on
  my JFrame and pass it over to the createImage function it shows every
  control/component and their content is shown on the Main JFrame but the 
  **applet** will not appear even though it is showing me my game it is sending back black screen shots of that portion.

**How it is loaded in my application:**

The following conditions are for my applet.

- Applet is on Main JFrame
- Stub of Applet implements AppletContext, AppletStub

Main JFrame -> Calls class named **Loader** and passes parameters to it -> Parameters are passed to my class called **Stub** from Loader -> Applet is set to the Stub -> Applet is added to Main JFrame centered.

I don't understand why this Component cannot be captured along with the others on the Main JFrame. I know the Applet is a Component of awt not JComponent of swing and I have tried just a screenshot of Applet by returning it from the Loader class and passing just Component to createImage overriding the signature, it seemed to only capture a small window which was different than capturing the Main JFrame of my application but nonetheless it was a black image.

Comment: Do you have to use `Robot`?

Comment: IIRC JFrame has a getRectangle() method, in which case I could imagine using that as opposed to screenRect would do

Comment: Robot is not required at all. Suggestions are open and welcome.

Comment: 1) See `ComponentImageCapture` in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5853992/edit). 2) Tip: Add @Dando18 (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewThompson I will test now.

Comment: How are you drawing to the Applet?  And like Thompson said, an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (tl;dr short runnable example) would help us understand how to fix the issue.

Comment: @Dando18 *"(tl;dr short runnable example)"* Great suggestion. And a tip: `[mcve]` in a comment will auto-expand to [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have to use `Robot` this should return a BufferedImage of a component.

```
public static BufferedImage createImage(JComponent comp) {
    int w = comp.getWidth();
    int h = comp.getHeight();
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
    comp.paint(g);
    return bi;
}
```

And simply call:

```
BufferedImage component_screenshot = createImage(myComponent);
```

Or using `Robot`:

```
try {
    BufferedImage img = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(
                                      frame.getLocationOnScreen().x,
                                      frame.getLocationOnScreen().y,
                                      frame.getWidth(),
                                      frame.getHeight()));
} catch (AWTException ex) {
}
```

Comment: This approach doesn't work if the component's area's rendering depends on other component that is not its child, e.g. the component is transparent.

Comment: @HeseinBurg the second approach won't work if the window is closed. You can try the first approach understanding what Coderino said.

Comment: The first part i am getting just my main application now but unfortunately does not render my Java Applet in the screen shots as Coderino suggested. I add my Applet to my main Frame (the one i am screenshotting) is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: *"..is there anyway to fix this?"* For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/) of your attempt.